# Pandas dataframe select rows where a list-column contains any of a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
  molecule            species
0        a              [dog]
1        b       [horse, pig]
2        c         [cat, dog]
3        d  [cat, horse, pig]
4        e     [chicken, pig]
```

and I like to extract a DataFrame containing only thoses rows, that contain any of `selection = ['cat', 'dog']`. So the result should look like this:

```
  molecule            species
0        a              [dog]
1        c         [cat, dog]
2        d  [cat, horse, pig]
```

What would be the simplest way to do this?

For testing:

```
selection = ['cat', 'dog']
df = pd.DataFrame({'molecule': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'species' : [['dog'], ['horse','pig'],['cat', 'dog'], ['cat','horse','pig'], ['chicken','pig']]})
```

Comment: Use `df = df.loc[df.species.str.contains('cat|dog'),:]`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

IIUC Re-create your df then using `isin` with `any` should be faster than `apply`

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.species.tolist()).isin(selection).any(1).values]
Out[64]: 
  molecule            species
0        a              [dog]
2        c         [cat, dog]
3        d  [cat, horse, pig]
```

Comment: This is nicely done - the only caveat is that if your index is not sequential integer (my specific problem, not the OP's), you have to add an index=df.index argument to your dataframe constructor.  e.g. df[pd.DataFrame(df.species.tolist(), index=df.index).isin(selection).any(1)]

Comment: @James_SO adding values at the end ~

Answer (score 20):

You can use `mask` with `apply` here.

```
selection = ['cat', 'dog']

mask = df.species.apply(lambda x: any(item for item in selection if item in x))
df1 = df[mask]
```

For the DataFrame you've provided as an example above, df1 will be:

```
molecule    species
0   a   [dog]
2   c   [cat, dog]
3   d   [cat, horse, pig]
```

Comment: Given that @NicoH is looking for the presence of  'cat' or 'dog', i would recommend changing the mask to this `mask = df.species.apply(lambda x: any(item for item in selection if item in x))`

Comment: @rs311 agreed - updated the lambda with selection example

Answer (score 12):

Using pandas `str.contains` ([uses regular expression](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)):

```
df[~df["species"].str.contains('(cat|dog)', regex=True)]
```

Output:

```
    molecule    species
1   b   [horse, pig]
4   e   [chicken, pig]
```

Answer (score 9):

Using Numpy would be much faster than using Pandas in this case,

Option 1: Using numpy intersection,

```
mask =  df.species.apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x, selection).size > 0)
df[mask]
450 µs ± 21.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

    molecule    species
0   a   [dog]
2   c   [cat, dog]
3   d   [cat, horse, pig]
```

Option2: A similar solution as above using numpy in1d,

```
df[df.species.apply(lambda x: np.any(np.in1d(x, selection)))]
420 µs ± 17.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Option 3: Interestingly, using pure python set is quite fast here

```
df[df.species.apply(lambda x: bool(set(x) & set(selection)))]
305 µs ± 5.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy and basic approach.
You can create a function that checks if the elements in `Selection list` are present in the pandas column `list`.

```
def check(speciesList):
    flag = False
    for animal in selection:
        if animal in speciesList:
            flag = True
    return flag
```

You could then use this `list` to create a column that contains `True` or `False` based on whether the record contains at least one element in Selection List and create a new data frame based on it.

```
df['containsCatDog'] = df.species.apply(lambda animals: check(animals))
newDf = df[df.containsCatDog == True]
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
import  pandas as pd
import numpy as np
selection = ['cat', 'dog']
df = pd.DataFrame({'molecule': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'species' : [['dog'], ['horse','pig'],['cat', 'dog'], ['cat','horse','pig'], ['chicken','pig']]})

df1 = df[df['species'].apply((lambda x: 'dog' in x) )]
df2=df[df['species'].apply((lambda x: 'cat' in x) )]
frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames,join='inner',ignore_index=False)
print("result",result)
result = result[~result.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help to filter out what you want.

```
new_df = df[~df['species'].isin(filter_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `str.get_dummies()`

```
df.loc[df['species'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()[selection].any(axis=1)]
```

or `explode()`

```
df.loc[df['species'].explode().isin(selection).groupby(level=0).any()]
```

or `set.intersection()`

```
df.loc[df['species'].map(lambda x: set(x).intersection(selection)).str.len().gt(0)]
```

Output:

```
  molecule            species
0        a              [dog]
2        c         [cat, dog]
3        d  [cat, horse, pig]
```