# Pandas dataframe select rows where a list-column contains a specific set of elements

Tags: pandas, string, list

This is a follow-up to the following post: [Pandas dataframe select rows where a list-column contains any of a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342715/pandas-dataframe-select-rows-where-a-list-column-contains-any-of-a-list-of-strin)

I want to be able to select rows that contain the exact pair of strings from the selection list (where selection= ['cat', 'dog']).

starting df:

```
  molecule            species
0        a              [dog]
1        b       [horse, pig]
2        c         [cat, dog]
3        d  [cat, horse, pig]
4        e     [chicken, pig]
```

df I want:

```
  molecule            species
2        c         [cat, dog]
```

I tried the following and it returned only the columns labels.

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.species.tolist()).isin(selection).all(1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
df['joined'] = df.species.str.join(sep=',')
selection = ['cat,dog']
filtered = df.loc[df.joined.isin(selection)]
```

This won't find cases with different sorting (i.e. `'dog,cat'` or `'horse,cat,pig'`), but if that is not an issue then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This will find anything.

```
import pandas as pd
selection = ['cat', 'dog']
mols = pd.DataFrame({'molecule':['a','b','c','d','e'],'species':[['dog'],['horse','pig'],['cat','dog'],['cat','horse','pig'],['chicken','pig']]})
mols.loc[np.where(pd.Series([all(w in selection for w in mols.species.values[k]) for k in mols.index]).map({True:1,False:0}) == 1)[0]]
```

If you want to find any rows that have at least the elements in the list (and could have others as well), use:

```
mols.loc[np.where(pd.Series([all(w in mols.species.values[k] for w in selection) for k in mols.index]).map({True:1,False:0}) == 1)[0]]
```

This is an interesting application of matrices as selectors. Use the transposed mols to multiply the vector of zeroes and ones that points which rows in mols fit your criteria:

```
mols.to_numpy().T.dot(pd.Series([all(w in mols.species.values[k] for w in selection) for k in mols.index]).map({True:1,False:0}))
```

Another (more readable) solution would be to assign, to mols, a column where the condition is True, map it to 0 and 1 and query mols where that column is equal to 1.