# How to group by data in a column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with 8,000 rows of data and a small sample of it here:

```
Customer         ItemDescription       Invoice     PurchaseDate
  1064               Produce            55514         22-01
  1064               Snack              55514         22-01
  1080               Drink              56511         23-01
  1080               Snack              56511         23-01
  1230               Drink              55551         26-03
  1230               Snack              55551         26-03
  1128               Meat               55003         04-03
  1128               Snack              55003         04-03
  1229               Drink              55100         06-03
  1229               Snack              55100         06-03
  1230               Meat               55102         07-03
  1230               Snack              55102         07-03
```

I am trying to find the top 3 items that customers have bought along with "Snack".

So the printed result should look like this:

```
0 Drink
1 Meat
2 Produce
```

I have tried df.groupby but it doesn't sort them based on what was purchased along with "snacks".

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby. By using groupby, you can group the products according to the customers and store them in the form of a list.

```
dfx=df.groupby('Customer').agg({'ItemDescription':list})
'''
                      ItemDescription
Customer                             
1064                 [Produce, Snack]
1080                   [Drink, Snack]
1128                    [Meat, Snack]
1229                   [Drink, Snack]
1230      [Drink, Snack, Meat, Snack]
'''
```

Here we will need to filter out customers who have not purchased a snack.

```
dfx=dfx[pd.DataFrame(dfx.ItemDescription.tolist()).isin(['Snack']).any(1).values]  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343080/15415267
```

Then, convert the remaining rows into a list and get distributions with the **Counter** function.

```
products=dfx.explode('ItemDescription')['ItemDescription'].to_list()
#['Produce', 'Snack', 'Drink', 'Snack', 'Meat', 'Snack', 'Drink', 'Snack', 'Drink', 'Snack', 'Meat', 'Snack']

from collections import Counter
occurence_count = Counter(top)
occurence_count.most_common(4) #get top 4 product 
#[('Snack', 6), ('Drink', 3), ('Meat', 2), ('Produce', 1)]
```

If you convert results to dataframe:

```
final =pd.DataFrame(occurence_count.most_common(4),columns=['product','count'])
'''
    product count
0   Snack   6
1   Drink   3
2   Meat    2
3   Produce 1

'''
```

or (shorter):

```
dfx=df.groupby('Customer').agg({'ItemDescription':list})
'''
                      ItemDescription
Customer                             
1064                 [Produce, Snack]
1080                   [Drink, Snack]
1128                    [Meat, Snack]
1229                   [Drink, Snack]
1230      [Drink, Snack, Meat, Snack]
'''

dfx=dfx[pd.DataFrame(dfx.ItemDescription.tolist()).isin(['Snack']).any(1).values]  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343080/15415267
products=dfx2.explode('ItemDescription')['ItemDescription'].value_counts()[0:4]
'''
      ItemDescription
Snack   6
Drink   3
Meat    2
Produce 1

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC your requirement is to get the top items that were taken along with "Snack". So you first want to filter those Customers who didn't buy snack.
Use [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) for that. And then you want to compute the top items in terms of count. For that you use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and then you take top 3 other than "Snack".

```
s = (
    df.groupby("Customer")
    .filter(lambda x: "Snack" not in x)["ItemDescription"]
    .value_counts()
)
top_3 = s.loc[s.index.difference(["Snack"])][:3]
```

print(top_3):

```
Drink      3
Meat       2
Produce    1
```